# Looking into email Class with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

Having the following class:

```
[Serializable]
public class EmailClass
{
    public string from;
    public List<string> To;
    public List<string> CC;
    public string DisplayTo;
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public int attachments;      
    public List<string> attachmentsName;
    public string DateTimeReceived;
    public string DateTimeSent;
    public string FinalFilename;
    public string DatetimeCreated;
    public string ExchangeUniqueId;
    public string ChankeyID;
    public string  FinalFileName {get;set;}
    public bool Encrypted;
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

}
```

Once the object is deserialized, I'm looking into all the mail address containers.
Im creating a search filter who is looking into `from` address, List `To` Collection,
and List `CC` collection.

So finally my linq query is like this:

```
listaCorreos.DataSource = 
    listado.Where(
        l => l.from.ToUpper().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToUpper()) ||
        l.To.Any((c) => c.ToUpper().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToUpper()) ||
        l.CC.Any((s) => s.ToUpper().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToUpper())
    )))
    .ToList();
```

Is any other way of doing it?. Maybe another one with best performance?. What would be
the best approach of searching inside a string variable and several List variables.

Comment: using contains in comparision is a bad idea, consider this two mails: `abc@mail.com` and `aabc@mail.com` <- contains will return true for it's comparision

Comment: The first thing you better do is prepare the *textBox1.Text.ToUpper()* beforehand and store it in a local variable. Don't forget that there is a new string being created each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather to that way

```
listado.Where(
               l =>
               l.from.Equals(textbox1.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
               l.To.Any((c) => c.Equals(textBox1.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
               l.CC.Any((s) => s.Equals(textBox1.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
             ))).ToList();
```

`StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` will ignore case while comparing, so you don't need ToUpper. You had mistake with `Contains` using contains on string (not `list<string>`) will fail when you consider mails like:

`abc@mail.com` and `aabc@mail.com` -> aabc@mail.com contains abc@mail.com, when using `string.Equals` it will return false as wanted.

EDIT:

one-liner:

```
listado.Where(x => 
                new List<string>{ x.from }.Union(x.To)
                      .Union(x.CC)
                      .Any(y => y.Equals(textbox1.Text, 
                                         StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: Would that one-liner work? Because `from` is a string (`IEnumerable<char>`) and `To` && `CC` are `List<string>`. So would the union work?

Comment: error CS1929: Instance argument: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>'

Comment: of course won't missed that, I thought (don't know why, that from is a `List<string>()`). Correcting, thanks